# QT printsupport lib missing from plugins - how to get it?

Tags: macos, qt

I am trying to build ios app on osx and Qt, but it gives me an error:

```
Project ERROR: unknown module(s) in QT: printsupport
```

After excluding QPrinter classes, project builds fine, so the rest of Qt works... Version: 5.12.6

I build this project on windows with no problem. My plugin dir on osx lacks the "printsupport" folder (present on windows). How can i get one? I used the official installer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment on QTBUG-79124](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-79124?focusedCommentId=481125&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-481125), the printsupport library was empty on iOS, so it was removed.  We were able to work around this for our project by adding

```
!ios {
    QT += printsupport
}
```

to our .pro file and guarding includes of `QPrinter` with `#ifndef Q_OS_IOS/#endif`.  Our code that used `QPrinter` was already within those guards.